# result ok load page into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have written a little function to check if the username/password of a certain user is correct using a json query. If result is ok i want to load a certain page into a div, if the result is error i want to load a different page into a div.

Normally i would use `$('#test').load("members.php");` to achieve this but it just isnt working (my div has an id of test - members is the page to be loaded).

```
function dologin(){
    var email = $('#email').val();
    var wachtwoord = $('#wachtwoord').val();

    if($.trim(email) != '' && $.trim(wachtwoord) != ''){
        $.post("login2.php", {email:email,wachtwoord:wachtwoord})

            .done(function(data) {
                var response    = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
                var result  = response.result;

                if(result == 'ok')
                {
                    // logged on
                    $('#test').load("members.php");
                }else{
                    // error
                    $('#test').load("loginfailed.php");
                }
         }, "json");
    }
}
```

Comment: What's not working?  What errors are you seeing?  What kind of response do you see in your browser's dev tools console?  What about on your server?  Got some HTML to show us?

Comment: Well i can log in that works (get json result OK) but the page i want to be loaded into a div isnt loading it just shows me a blank screen. I can load members.php manually but it doesnt go there automaticly. (same goes for when credentials are invalid) So basicly    $('#test').load("members.php"); isnt doing anything

Comment: Please try to pass the PATH to members.php instead of just `members.php`

Comment: no luck :( it also is in the same container so it should be able to find it. When i use a button and function members(){
    $('#test').load('members.php');
   } it loads just fine

Comment: It's hard to tell without additional input. Can you access the members.php directly? does it return a valid html code? does the response has a response.result? 
If you can, show us: 1. the response object, 2. The members.php 3. loginfailed.php